# UIBarButtonItem stops working after I change enabled property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have a UIBarButton that is connected, through the interface builder, to the following method:

```
- (void)btnJumpToStart_Touch:(id)sender {
     index = 0;
     [self setCurrentPage];
     [self showCard];
}
```

`index` is defined early in the implementation.  `setCurrentPage` is this:

```
- (void)setCurrentPage {

    // I need to set the bottom page control first,
    // this allows me to display that the user is viewing the 
    // first half of the deck or the second
    if(index < 11) {
        [self.bottomPageControl setCurrentPage:0];
    }
    else {
        [self.bottomPageControl setCurrentPage:1];
    }

    // now we set the top page control.  I use the index that is being displayed,
    // then divided by whether or not the bottom page control is showing the 
    // first half, or the second
    [self.topPageControl setCurrentPage:(index - ((deck.count / 2) * self.bottomPageControl.currentPage))];

    // next I set the 'jump to end/jump to start' button's enabled properties

    // the jump to end will only be anabled when the 
    // index is less than the deck's count - 1
    if(index < ([deck count] - 1)) {
        [self.btnJumpToEnd setEnabled:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.btnJumpToEnd setEnabled:NO];
    }

    // the jump to start will only be enabled when the
    // index is greater than 0
    if(index > 0) {
        [[self btnJumpToStart] setEnabled:YES];
    }
    else {
        [[self btnJumpToStart] setEnabled:NO];
    }

}
```

Finally, `showCard` is this:

```
- (void)showCard {
    Card *card = [deck cardAtIndex:index];
    [cardImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:card.imageFile]];
}
```

Now, as you can see, the `btnJumpToStart` will be disabled, or enabled, in the `setCurrentPage` method.  it will start out as disabled (I set it as such in the IB).  When the criteria is met to 'enable' the button, it doesn't work properly.  The `index` will be set to 0, but it won't set the current page properly, and the card is not shown.  The weird thing is that after a few presses of the button, it might work.

Very intermittent...

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: I believe that this line - (void)btnJumpToStart_Touch:(id)sender should be changed to - (IBAction)btnJumpToStart_Touch:(id)sender. If you set up button in the IB then when you connect a new action to the button you need to set the methods as IBActions.

Comment: @Popeye No, as long as its declared IBOutlet in the .h, it's fine.  Void and IBOutlet are typedefs of each other.

Comment: IBAction resolves to "void" and IBOutlet resolves to nothing, but they signify to Xcode and Interface builder that these variables and methods can be used in Interface builder to link UI elements to your code.
If you're not going to be using Interface Builder at all, then you don't need them in your code, but if you are going to use it, then you need to specify IBAction for methods that will be used in IB and IBOutlet for objects that will be used in IB. So if you are linking this method up in Interface builder then you need to declare the method as IBAction.

Comment: Displaying (void) instead of (IBAction) was a mistake, but I tried changing it up in code and it made no difference.

Comment: Tried setting breakpoints and seeing if the setEnabled call is reached?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `-(void)btnJumpToStart_Touch:(id)sender` to `-(IBAction)btnJumpToStart_Touch:(id)sender` as @Popeye mentioned. If that doesn't work, try creating and adding the `UIBarButton` programatically in the controller's `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Yeah, the only problem is that when I comment out the part of `setCurrentPage` that deals with enabling/disabling the buttons, I have no problem...

Comment: where or what calls `btnJumpToStart_Touch:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I commented out the code that enabled/disabled the controls.  Then I made it so that the buttons are enabled in the IB.

I played around with the product in the simulator.  ONce I was done with that, I uncommented out that code, then set the buttons back to be disabled in the beginning.  Now it works...